# React Delete record and redirect user to Dashboard Page with updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reducers

I want to delete specific record which i am in its detailed page and upon delete i want to user to redirect main list page.

Now using this code i am able to delete record but i am getting error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'xxx' of undefined which i am assuming that after deletion of the individual record like #1 it will try to re render the same page and in the fact that deleted record data will not be there in state so it will throw " Cannot read property"

Now my end goal is to move user from this detailed page to list page where i cans see list of persons not able to find after deletion how to redirect user to another page.

In my case i have person list lets say i have two persons in the list with ID =1 and 2.

takes to person detailed page (like http://localhost:3000/persons/1) and there should be deleted and send back user to main list page with updated http://localhost:3000/persons/

Here is my code for

PersonDetailedHeader.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Segment, Image, Item, Header, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { deletePerson } from '../personsActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapState = (state) => ({
    persons: state.persons,
})

const actions = {

    deletePerson
}


class PersonsDetailedHeader extends Component {

    handleDeletePerson = personID => {
        this.props.deletePerson(personID);

    }


    render() {
        const { person } = this.props;

        const personImageStyle = {
            filter: 'brightness(30%)'

        };
        const personImageTextStyle =
        {
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: '5%',
            left: '5%',
            width: '100%',
            height: 'auto',
            color: 'white'
        };




        return (
            <Segment.Group>
                <Segment basic attached="top" style={{ padding: '0' }}>
                    <Image src={person.ImageURL} size="large" style={personImageStyle} />

                    <Segment basic style={personImageTextStyle}>
                        <Item.Group>
                            <Item>
                                <Item.Content>
                                    <Header
                                        size="huge"
                                        content={person.FullName}
                                        style={{ color: 'white' }}
                                    />
                                    <p>BirthDate:  <strong>{person.BirthDate}</strong></p>
                                    <p>
                                        Sex: <strong>{person.Sex}</strong>
                                    </p>
                                </Item.Content>
                            </Item>
                        </Item.Group>
                    </Segment>
                </Segment>

                <Segment attached="bottom">
                    <Button color="red" onClick={() => this.handleDeletePerson(person.id)}>
                        Delete Person</Button>



                    <Button color="orange" floated="right" as={Link} to={`/managePerson/${person.id}`}>
                        Manage Person
                </Button>
                </Segment>
            </Segment.Group >
        )

    }
}

export default connect(mapState, actions)(PersonsDetailedHeader);
```

PersonList.jsx

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import PersonListItem from './PersonListItem';

class PersonList extends Component {
    render() {
        const { persons, deletePerson } = this.props;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {persons.map(person => (
                    <PersonListItem
                        key={person.id}
                        person={person}
                        deletePerson={deletePerson} />
                ))}


            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default PersonList
```

PersonDashboard.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import PersonList from './PersonList/PersonList';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createPerson, updatePerson, deletePerson } from './personsActions';
import LoadingComponent from '../../app/layout/LoadingComponent';




const mapState = (state) => ({
    persons: state.persons,
    loading: state.async.loading
})


const actions = {
    createPerson,
    updatePerson,
    deletePerson
}


class PersonDashboard extends Component {


    handleDeletePerson = personID => {
        this.props.deletePerson(personID);
    }



    render() {

        const { persons, loading } = this.props;

        if (loading) return <LoadingComponent />
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Column width={12}>
                    <PersonList persons={persons} deletePerson={this.handleDeletePerson} />
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column width={3}>

                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>

        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapState, actions)(PersonDashboard)
```

Now following code are for my Person reducers which are as following

personsActions.js

```
import { CREATE_PERSON, UPDATE_PERSON, DELETE_PERSON, FETCH_PERSON } from "./personsConstants";

import { asyncActionStart, asyncActionFinish, asyncActionError } from "../async/asyncActions";
import { fetchSampleData } from "../../app/data/mockApi";
import { toastr } from "react-redux-toastr";

export const createPerson = (person) => {
    return async dispatch =>{
        try{
            dispatch({
                type: CREATE_PERSON,
                payload:{
                        person 
                    }
                })
                toastr.success('Sucess!','Person has been created');
        }
        catch(error){
            toastr.error('Opps !','Something went Wrong');
        }
    };
};


export const updatePerson = (person) =>{
    return async dispatch =>{
        try{
            dispatch({
                type: UPDATE_PERSON,
                payload:{
                    person 
                }
            })
            toastr.success('Upadate Sucess !','Person has been Sucessfully updated');
        }
        catch(error){
            toastr.error('Opps !','Something went wrong while update');
        }
    }

}

export const deletePerson = (personId) =>{
    return async dispatch =>{
        try{
            dispatch({
                type: DELETE_PERSON,
                payload:{
                    personId
                }
            })
            toastr.success('Sucess !','Person Deleted sucessfully');
        }
        catch(error){
            toastr.error('Opps !','Something went wrong while delete person');
        }
    }

}

export const loadPersons = () =>{
    return async dispatch =>{
        try{
            dispatch(asyncActionStart())
            const persons = await fetchSampleData();
            dispatch({type:FETCH_PERSON,payload:{persons}})
            dispatch(asyncActionFinish())
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error);
            dispatch(asyncActionError())
        }
    }
}
```

personReducer.js

```
import {createReducer} from '../../app/common/utils/reducerUtils';
import { CREATE_PERSON, UPDATE_PERSON, DELETE_PERSON, FETCH_PERSON } from './personsConstants';

const initState =[]

const createPerson = (state,payload) =>{
    return [...state,payload.person]
}

const updatePerson = (state,payload) =>{
    return [
        ...state.filter(person => person.id !== payload.person.id),payload.person
    ]
}


const deletePerson = (state,payload) =>{
    return [
        ...state.filter(person => person.id !== payload.personId)
    ]
}


const fetchPersons = (state,payload) =>{
        return payload.persons
}


export default createReducer(initState,{
    [CREATE_PERSON]: createPerson,
    [UPDATE_PERSON]: updatePerson ,
    [DELETE_PERSON]: deletePerson,
    [FETCH_PERSON]: fetchPersons
} )
```

Here is screen shot of Detailed page.
[image]

Comment: sorry, this question is just too long to read. if you don't get any answers, please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion now i have reduce it to an extent.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to have a check in the `render()` if person (or personId) exists? if so, render the detailed page of the person as you usually do... if person does not exists, then redirect it to the desired page (e.g. main list page).

So, the delete logic does not have redirect logic, just delete the person.